# unable to Pass hyphen or - character using Selenium webDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

from web driver for one textarea/input text if i am passing SendKeys("'1-ABCD'"),in text box onle '1ABCD' get enter.

Can anyone help me how to pass a value such that value get accepted as '1-ABCD'

Thanks.

Comment: are you able to write 1-ABCD manually in the text box?

Comment: if i am not wrong is it extjs framework with combobox control?